# iOS Capturing Video

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation

I want to make an app for the iPhone with the ability to record video. One thing I want to do with the video once it's recorded, is to take the audio from it and alter it, such as make it sound feminine or masculine etc. I've never done this before but is it better to use AVFoundation or UIImagePickerController. I've read that the UIImagePickerController is easier to use but will it allow be to extract and edit the audio of the recorded video and put it back in?

Any help or suggestions as to how to approach this are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hope this link will help you http://aroth.no-ip.org:82/wordpress/archives/673

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easiest to capture with UIImagePickerController if you do not need to alter it live. Once the video is captured and you have altered the audio track somehow, write it again using AVFoundation's AVMutableComposition and an audio mix.